# python source distribution (sdist) - generated data files

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

During the build of my package I am **generating** data files.

I would like to create source distribution (setup.py sdist), such as if they was originally in the source tree, **BUT**, I don't want to generate them in the source tree but on someplace else (preferably build/generated) to not clutter my source (and accidentally commit it).

For example, in the end I want to have ***data.txt*** under ***dist_root/generated/data.txt***
("dist_root" is where setup.py resides).

I used the ***data_files*** setuptools (not the package_data as this data is not of package) and encountered the following problems:

1. If I generate data.txt under build, it is pruned as the process is filtering any file under build_base.
2. If I generate it under some temp folder say **dist_root/temp/data.txt**, this "temp" folder is being chained.

so if I put **data_files = [('generated, temp/data.txt)]**, I will get in the distribution a chain path
**dist_root/generated/temp/data.txt**

Seems like my only choice is to generate it under **dist_root/generated/data.txt**
but then, again, I'm cluttering my source tree and can not know how to clean it as this "generated" folder name is dynamic.

**Any workarounds?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Preferred solution: write files to source dir, remove them after `sdist` finishes

You can override the `sdist` command to write files in the source dir and clean them up after the command finishes:

```
import os
from distutils import dir_util

from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.sdist import sdist as sdist_orig


class sdist(sdist_orig):

    def run(self):
        # generate data files
        genbase = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'temp')
        self.mkpath(genbase)
        with open(os.path.join(genbase, 'data.txt'), 'w') as fp:
            fp.write('hello distutils world')
        # run original sdist
        super().run()
        # clean up generated data files
        dir_util.remove_tree(genbase, dry_run=self.dry_run)


setup(
    ...
    data_files=[
        ('generated', ['temp/data.txt']),
    ],
    cmdclass={'sdist': sdist},
)
```

---

### Generating data files without writing them to source dir

#### Adapting source metadata in the `sdist` temp

Although dirty enough, the least hacky way possible would be updating the source metadata directly in the sdist dir. This way, you will still have a valid egg metadata and don't have to deal with missing source files on the whole `sdist` way.

```
genfiles = ['temp/data.txt']


class sdist(sdist_orig):

    def make_release_tree(self, base_dir, files):
        super().make_release_tree(base_dir, files)
        for path in genfiles:
            fullpath = os.path.join(base_dir, path)
            self.mkpath(os.path.dirname(fullpath))
            if not self.dry_run:
                with open(fullpath, 'w') as fp:
                fp.write('hello distutils world')
            # also adapt source metadata file
            cmd_egg_info = self.get_finalized_command('egg_info')
            sourcemeta = os.path.join(base_dir, 
                                      cmd_egg_info.egg_name + '.egg-info', 
                                      'SOURCES.txt')
            with open(sourcemeta, 'a') as fp:
                fp.write('\n')
                fp.write(path)


setup(
    ...,
    data_files=[
        ('generated', genfiles),
    ],
    cmdclass={'sdist': sdist},
)
```

Basically, the generated data files are simply ignored until the actual copying of source files happens. Then, the files are generated (as a substitution to copying existing files), and, since the source metadata would be otherwise incomplete, it is updated with the generated files.

#### Write non-existing files in metadata

**I would strongly recommend against doing that.**

All the other approaches would be much more dirty as they would write non-existent files to metadata and make `distutils`/`setuptools` to ignore the non-existing files on the whole way of generating source distribution. But if you insist, here's a solution with least possible monkeypatching:

```
genfiles = ['temp/data.txt']


class FileList(setuptools.command.egg_info.FileList):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.files += genfiles

    def _safe_path(self, path):
        return path in genfiles or super()._safe_path(path)


class sdist(sdist_orig):

    def run(self):
        # monkeypatch begin
        FileListOrig = setuptools.command.egg_info.FileList
        setuptools.command.egg_info.FileList = FileList
        # monkeypatch end
        super().run()
        # restore the original class
        setuptools.command.egg_info.FileList = FileListOrig

    def make_release_tree(self, base_dir, files):
        super().make_release_tree(base_dir, files)
        for path in genfiles:
            fullpath = os.path.join(base_dir, path)
            self.mkpath(os.path.dirname(fullpath))
            if not self.dry_run:
                with open(fullpath, 'w') as fp:
                    fp.write('hello distutils world')


setup(
    ...,
    data_files=[
        ('generated', genfiles),
    ],
    cmdclass={'sdist': sdist},
)
```

Comment: Thanks,I am aware of this soultion.
 I am asking specifically if I can do it without writing/generating to src.

Comment: Although you can do that, it is extremely hacky and I wouldn't recommend doing that. The reason for this is that `setuptools` generates the egg metadata first, then copies the files in `sdist`, so you will have to additionally adapt `egg_info` command, which can easily break your working dir until you clean up `mypkg.egg_info/` manually. If you want to take that risk, I can update the answer with the direct approach.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will go on the src writing option with clean and .gitignore protection.